# A space curve with constant curvature-torsion product

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry

How do we solve for  curve coordinates in terms of parameter $t$  in $\mathbb R^3$ having scalar property

$$ \tau \cdot \kappa = const.?$$

The curve would be with infinite twist at straight portions and confined to plane at cusp points.

EDITS (1-3):

I.e., how to find a vector $r(t)$ so that

$$  \tau\, \kappa =\dfrac{r^{'} \times r^{''}\cdot r^{'''}  }{||r^{'} \times r^{''}||^2 }  \dfrac{|r^{'} \times r^{''}|  }{|r^{'} |^3 } =1? $$

The above formulae are of Frenet-Serret vector triad  [$T,N,B$](https://www.math.uh.edu/~minru/summ11/two2.pdf) and derivatives, textbook derived with respect to parameter $t$.

BTW, is there a word for *infinite torsion* of a line?( By analogy of infinite normal curvature being a cusp)

The following surface (rotation symmetry assumed) and arc are obtained numerically but not without an extra assumed *arbitrary relation of arc angle to meridian and axis of symmetry*. Central parts are asymptotic/infinite torsion and the ends have infinite curvature cusp edge/zero torsion just as expected. This singularity terminates numerical computation.

[image]

Comment: Every helix satisfies your condition.

Comment: Is not the quotient $ \dfrac{\kappa}{ \tau } $ (but not  product ) constant for general helices?

Comment: The quotient, product, sum, difference, etc. of $\kappa$ and $\tau$ is constant for any helix because both $\kappa$ and $\tau$ are individually constant.

Comment: As it is *not * a helix, I  placed its name in quotes, Anyhow now changed the title. Proceeding from derivative definition it would not be any helix, I think.